# How to add buttons inside calendarview?

Tags: android, calendarview

I'm trying to use standart calendarView(api >11)  in myapp,but i was suprised that switching between months can be done only throught scrolling. I wan't to add buttons previous and next to calendar view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttlayaout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:text="Previous" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:text="Next" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </CalendarView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

By my knowledge you cant add buttons to the Calendar view. You can however make a selection.

I've made a horizontal scroll view with 5 years across from now. And another horizontal scroll view for the months. 
After extracting the selected month and year. you can select the `CalendarView.setData()` with your own date and till set the date for you